# extension ACL for activity types error "[] operator not supported for strings"

Tags: activities, debug

WP 5.3 civi 5.19.3 php 7

select contact record - error as follows:

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/leepngo/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl-master/activitytypeacl.php:278 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/leepngo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(300): activitytypeacl_civicrm_selectWhereClause('Activity', Array) 
#1 /home/leepngo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/WordPress.php(155): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks(Array, 'civicrm_selectW...', 2, 'Activity', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) 
#2 /home/leepngo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(90): CRM_Utils_Hook_WordPress->invokeViaUF(2, 'Activity', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'civicrm_selectW...') 
#3 /home/leepngo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(184): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), 'hook_civicrm_se...', Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher)) 
#4 /h in /home/leepngo/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl-master/activitytypeacl.php on line 278
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are running very old version of Activity acl extension. The issue you facing must have been [fixed](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl/commit/487253a3325049304ed5fa56e79a9fc3e038124b) last year. Can you update the extension by [downloading](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl/archive/master.zip) from here?

Comment: perfect Thanks Pradeep